# Concurrence of three chords

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

The center $A$ of a circle lies on another circle which cuts the former in $B,C$. $AD$ is a chord of the latter circle meeting $BC$ in $E$. From $D$ are drawn $DF$ and $DG$ to touch the former circle. Prove that $G,E$ and $F$ lie on a straight line.
I tried inversion, but could not prove the result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why must this be true? i drew a rough sketch and GEF are not in  a straight line... how exactly are DF and DG drawn?

Comment: @Sid $D$ is any point on (second) circle passing through $A$ and $DF,DG$ are tangents to first circle, with center $A$. The question could have been worded more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the circle $(A)$ be $C_1$ and $(ABC)$ be $C_2$. Note $A,F,D,G$ lie on a circle. Call it $C_3$.

[image]

Now $BC$ is radical axis of $C_1,C_2$. Since $C_2,C_3$ intersect in $A,D$, their radical axis is $AD$. Since $C_1,C_3$ intersect in $F,G$, their radical axis is $FG$.

Since none of these three circles are concentric, by radical axis theorem, $BC$, $AD$, $FG$ concur at the $E$. Hence $E$ is collinear with $F,G$.

Comment: Thank you.Being unfamiliar with the radical axis theorem,I attempted a proof from first principals,but will now study the foregoing topic. Thanks once again.

Comment: @D.Spencer I find it surprising that you don't know power of a point, but are willing to try inversion. I would encourage you to learn that first.